# VMware Esxi with Kingston SSDNow (No Trim but S.M.A.R.T Garbage Collection)

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssd, trim

I recently posted asking whether Trim is supported on VMware Esxi ([here](https://serverfault.com/questions/231679/ssd-on-vmware-esxi-4-trim-good-idea)) and found out it is **NOT.**

I've read that some SSDs, such as the [Kingston SSDNow](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4010/kingston-ssdnow-v-plus-100-review) have hardware garbage collection. Would this work within ESXi and compensate for the lack of Trim? (Drives wouldn't lose performance or degrade to quickly).

To quote:

```
this drive uses the T6UG1XBG controller but with updated firmware. The new firmware enables two things: very aggressive OS-independent garbage collection and higher overall performance.
```

Comment: really nobody??? :(